# Progress Bar Java exit

Tags: java, swing, progress

i am doing a quiz in java and i figured out everything except i want to put in a progressbar.I want to exit my actual frame(or to show something) when the progress bar is filled(i used it as a timer), how can i do it? I don't know how to do something when the bar is filled. The code i have so far, it's a progress bar that fills for 30 secs or something very close to that.

```
al=new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            if(jProgressBar1.getValue()<100){
                jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue()+5);
            }
            else{t.stop();}
        }
    };

    t=new Timer(1500,al);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, put more code into this `else{t.stop();}` block. Here is where you would exit whatever it is you wish to exit.

```
else {
    t.stop();
    // exit whatever window you wish to exit
}
```

Note that this is as about as detailed as we can go since you've not given more information about your current code.

Obligatory link: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)